# Javascript - How to ONLY append rows of data that has been MODIFIED from a spreadsheet B onto spreadsheet A

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I want to create a script that appends data from sheet B onto sheet A. The first time it should append all the rows of data onto sheet A. However, overtime some of the data in sheet B might change and so I ONLY want to append those rows of data that has been modified. The easier option would be clearing all data and re-appending the new set of data. But I don't want that as it will cause some issues.

So how can I write a loop and if statement which checks through the array of data from sheet B and compares it to an array of data in Sheet A. And if the rows are different, add those rows to maybe a different array and append that array to the end of Sheet A.

```
     var pulleddata = datasheet.getRange(2, 1, datasheet.getLastRow(), datasheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var currentdata = currentsheet.getRange(2, 1, currentsheet.getLastRow(), currentsheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  

  for( var i = 0; i< pulleddata.length;i++ ) {
    
    
    var mcleod =           pulleddata[i][0];
    var firstname =        pulleddata[i][2];
    var lastname =         pulleddata[i][3];
    var status =           pulleddata[i][16];
    var program =          pulleddata[i][41];
    var email =            pulleddata[i][39];
    var gender =           pulleddata[i][5];
    var dob =              pulleddata[i][6];
    var degreePool =       pulleddata[i][9];
    var degree =           pulleddata[i][10];
    var degreeMajor =      pulleddata[i][11];
    var university =       pulleddata[i][12];
    var campus =           pulleddata[i][13];
    var firstSem =         pulleddata[i][14];
    var lastSem =          pulleddata[i][15];
    var suburb =           pulleddata[i][34];
    var state =            pulleddata[i][35];
    var postcode =         pulleddata[i][36];
    var dateJoined =       pulleddata[i][69];
    
    var pulledDataArray =[mcleod, firstname, lastname, status, program, email, gender, dob, degreePool, degree, degreeMajor, university, campus, firstSem, lastSem, suburb, state, postcode, dateJoined];
    
    
    for( var j = 0; j< currentdata.length;j++ ) {
      
    var mcleod =           currentdata[j][0];
    var firstname =        currentdata[j][1];
    var lastname =         currentdata[j][2];
    var status =           currentdata[j][3];
    var program =          currentdata[j][4];
    var email =            currentdata[j][5];
    var gender =           currentdata[j][6];
    var dob =              currentdata[j][7];
    var degreePool =       currentdata[j][8];
    var degree =           currentdata[j][9];
    var degreeMajor =      currentdata[j][10];
    var university =       currentdata[j][11];
    var campus =           currentdata[j][12];
    var firstSem =         currentdata[j][13];
    var lastSem =          currentdata[j][14];
    var suburb =           currentdata[j][15];
    var state =            currentdata[j][16];
    var postcode =         currentdata[j][17];
    var dateJoined =       currentdata[j][18];
      
    var currentDataArray =[mcleod, firstname, lastname, status, program, email, gender, dob, degreePool, degree, degreeMajor, university, campus, firstSem, lastSem, suburb, state, postcode, dateJoined];
   
      var modifiedData = [];
      if ( i[0] == j[0]) {
        if ( i != j) {
        modifiedData.push(i[0])
        } else modifiedData.push(j[0]);
      } else {modifiedData.push(i[0])
             }
      Logger.log(modifiedData);
   };
    currentsheet.appendRow(modifiedData);
  };
```

Comment: Do you mean to run this script only once? What should happen if you run it again? It will found the different rows again and append them again and you will get two copies of different rows?

Comment: Obvious solution is to mark somehow the changed lines. And to append only marked lines (and remove the marks). Or to copy every changed row with `onEdit()` trigger as soon as it was changed.

Comment: The script will run fortnightly or monthly, and so every time it is run, it should append all the edited rows from sheet B onto sheet A.

Comment: *all the edited rows* sounds vague. Look. Moth 1: some row: "a, b, c". Month 2: "aa, b, c" -- it was edit, it will be append. Month 3: "aaa, b, c" -- append again. Month 4: "aa, b, c" -- it's *edited*, but it looks like the row from Month 2, should it be append?

Comment: And as far as I can tell @Goran's algorithm doesn't recognize the cases when several rows were filled (edited!) with the same data: ["a,b,c", "d,e,f", "g,h,i"] --> ["abc","abc","abc"] Since there won't be new hashes. The same is true if some rows will be removed or changed its place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to have a formula to calculate hash over all the rows in sheet B. When you copy the rows from B to A, you will include the hash and copy it as value. This will allow you to easy compare the hashes to determine which rows in the sheet B has been changed (or added).

Please note the formulas in D1 and E1 (see screenshots below).

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L6pOIQylgsP1hMbY48SOI0FSbHMSH7gguAljwtFGlvY/copy) is the sample sheet.

[image]
[image]

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
const sha = ss.getSheetByName("A")
const shb = ss.getSheetByName("B")

/**
 * Returns a hash for the given range of rows
 * 
 * @param {"A1:C"} arr The input range to calculate hash for
 * @returns {string[]} The array of hashes
 * @customfunction
 */
function hash(arr){
  const result = arr.map(row=>{
    const values = row.map(cell=>String(cell)).join("")
    if(!values){
      // if empty row, return empty hash
      return [""]
    } else{
      const hash = Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.MD5, values)
      const hashString = hash.map(byte=>(byte+256).toString(16)).join("")
      return [hashString]
    }
  })
  return result
}


function compareAndAppend() {
  SpreadsheetApp.flush()
  const bValues = shb.getDataRange().getValues().slice(1)
  const colHasMatch = 5 // must be the last column!
  const newRows = bValues.filter(row=>!row[colHasMatch-1]).map(row=>row.slice(0,colHasMatch-1))
  if(newRows.length>0){
    sha.getRange(sha.getLastRow()+1, 1, newRows.length, newRows[0].length).setValues(newRows)
  }
}
```

Comment: I get this permission error when I tried to use your custom Hash function. 'Exception: You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openById. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets (line 2).' I did a bit of research and found out that when creating a custom function, it cannot look into a different spread sheet. Is there a solution to that?

Comment: You can use importrange function and import the other sheet into the active one

Comment: Hey @GoranK, is there a way to replace the edited rows of sheet B on top of the corresponding rows on Sheet A? and ONLY append if there has been completely new rows added to Sheet B.